# How to customize Title position with ChartJS

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Is it possible with ChartJS to place the position of the Title, aside from the standard `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` options exposed by ChartJS?

I'd prefer the Title in the Top Left of the canvas. Can't find anything in the documentation indicating whether this is doable, or if it can be adjusted via callback or plugin

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you should set Align to (start or center or end) for title:

```
 const options = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      color:'#8b93a2',
      align:'start',
      position:'top',
      text: 'Chart title',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation from [chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html#position) page

Only top,left,right and bottom are available.

Comment: Thanks - yes aware, but chartjs feels quite extensible so am trying to determine if a solution can be had perhaps with a callback or plugin that updates the property which sets Title position